# Python performance test script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm looking for a test script in Python to test a few things to see how fast/slow it completes on various systems.

Just some simple commands that are looped to make the script take say 10 second to complete and a report of how much cpu it uses, how much memory and how long it took to complete?

I guess for the memory part we would use `memory_profiler`, I guess `psutil` for the cpu calling out 5 readings one at the start (all separated by 2 seconds) then the average cpu usage used, 1 in the middle of the script and 5 at the end (all separated by 2 seconds)

How best would I go about this or is there already a script avaliable, I can't find anything that is good enough for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython has `%timeit`:

```
%timeit foo()
```

line_profiler and memory_profiler can be run from the IPython console:

```
%load_ext line_profiler
%load_exp memory_profiler

%lprun -f foo foo()
%mprun -f foo foo()
```

More details: http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/

Average CPU is... trickier. Linux does report a kind of average CPU usage over time, check this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145247/understanding-cpu-while-running-top-command

Comment: Problem is I can't use iPython in my situation.

Comment: @Ryflex: `ipython`'s `%timeit` is just a simplified way to use [`timeit.repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.repeat) which is part of the Python batteries available everywhere. Only difference is `repeat` requires the `setup` to import everything it needs (including stuff from `__main__` where `%timeit` gets the stuff from `__main__` automatically), and requires you to tweak `number` yourself instead of autoranging, but the feature is available no matter what.

Comment: @Ryflex IPython just makes it easier. Check out the link I provided, you can do all of this without IPython.